# Random like order with mysql and PHP

Tags: php, mysql, random

I use PHP and Mysql. I have a table that looks kind of like this:

```
id   title
----------
1    my title
2    another title
3    The last title
```

Now I want to select them with a random like order.

- I will need to use LIMIT because of the query size.
- The random like order should always be the same random order every time.

### Example result, every time

```
3   The last title
1   my title
2   another title
```

Do another query run:

```
3   The last title
1   my title
2   another title
```

The same random like result appear.

### Possible solutions

- Add a real random number stored as a new column generated by insert.
- Some fancy SELECT query that does some magic.
- Something else?

Why I want this is that I insert products, first from one site, then from another. In the result I want to present them as a mix.

Comment: Confused. So you wanna have 123, 312, 231, 321, etc?

Comment: "The random like order should always be the same random order every time" That's not really random, is it?

Comment: @iamgory That's why I wrote "random like".

Comment: @PraveenKumar No. If I the first time get them in the order 312, then I will always get them in that order. It should feel random but it should like be a static mixed order.

Comment: @JensTörnell Ha ha ha... :D Why not have another column, with some numbers and sort by that?

Comment: You means something like this? `select * from <tablename> where <cond> ORDER BY ONLY_RAND_THE_FIRST_TIME_AND_REMEMBER_WHAT_YOU_DID_FOR_EVERMORE() limit <startlimit>, <end limit>`

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yes! I guess I need a workaround for that. :)

Comment: Then the answer is _If you can write one of those let us know and we will all help your test it_

Comment: @RiggsFolly Maybe I've just got that magic query as an answer below. I'll need to try it with more data than 3 rows but hopefully it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not really random at all, but then again your request wouldn't work with random numbers. You want some sort of a hash of each record to use in the order by. You can probably find something better, but as a simple example you could use:

`SELECT * FROM my_table ORDER BY MOD(id, 2);`

Which you can see working here:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/269a4/1/0

Comment: Great! It seems to be the magic SQL query I'm looking for. My only concern is if it will work great with 1000 of results. I'll need to try it out.

Comment: Well the `MOD(id, 2)` won't be great for getting random results, but if you find some more convoluted way of getting a "random-like" distribution then you can put it in there instead. Just off the top of my head, I think a hash would be useful but you don't want something that is going to hurt your performance much, maybe you could look at `TO_BASE64()` and see how that works.

Comment: I just tried the `MOD` thing on more rows and it seems to work well. What do you see as pitfalls with it?

Comment: Well with MOD(id, 2) it's basically just saying "put the even ids first", so in a small sample you might not notice it, but once it gets bigger (e.g. 2,4,6,8,10,1,3,5,7,9) you probably want something to mess the order up more

Answer (score -6):

Use `ORDER BY RAND()`.So your query should be :

```
 select * from <tablename> where <cond> then ORDER BY RAND() limit <startlimit>, <end limit>
```

Comment: This will generate different results every time. I want the same results every time. "Random like".

Comment: why downvote??? What is your requirement?As per your question,  You want to show random data.Am i wrong?

Comment: @DipanwitaKundu Removed my downvote. See, he clearly explains you, you didn't read his comment on your answer right?

Comment: @DipanwitaKundu Yes, because you clearly didn't read their comment on your answer.